# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lab_utils_uni'

Tags: python-3.x, modulenotfounderror

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9FhS.png)

I am trying to run the optional labs of the machine learning specialization from Coursera.
I have put the `lab_utils_uni.py` under the same directory with the `t1.ipynb` notebook file.
I am using jupyter notebook on Pycharm.

---

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_7808\1071044293.py in <module>
----> 1 from lab_utils_uni import plt_intuition, plt_stationary, plt_update_onclick, soup_bowl

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lab_utils_uni'
```

Comment: Use `!ls` to see if you are in the right directory and the scripts are there. If not then change the directory to where you kept the `lab_utils_uni.py` file by using `os.chdir('path/to/lab_utils_uni.py')`. Then you should be able to import the module. Remember to `import os`.